# Cordova building android issue

Tags: android, cordova, ant, build

i'm building an android app with about 4Gig of local files ( most of them are songs ).
When i build my application for android using "cordova build android" command, i get the following error:

Compiling app on platform "android" via command

```
/Users/yveswebit/Desktop/APP/platforms/android/cordova/build

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: An error occurred while building the android project.Error executing "ant debug -f "/Users/yveswebit/Desktop/APP/platforms/android/build.xml"": 
BUILD FAILED
/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:932: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:950: null returned: 1

Total time: 23 seconds


at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/compile.js:65:22)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

When i'm builing my application with less songs, the build is succesfully.

Thanks for help